# htaccess redirect from root to subfolder and then mask the url?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, masking, subdirectory

Two things:

**Firstly** - I have version 2 of a website located in a folder named v2, and I want to redirect any traffic that is NOT a child of the v2 folder, to www.example.com/v2

The old site located in the root was created in iWeb and has a LOT of subfolders and sub-subfolders.

So:

www.example.com/v2 = New site

www.example.com/Page.html

www.example.com/category/Page.html

ww.example.com/category/subcategory/Page.html = All generic examples of what I need to redirect.

**Secondly**, and I don't know if this is possible, I want to hide /v2/ in the URL, so that visitors will just see www.example.com/page even though they are actually on www.example.com/v2/page

Links are hardcoded to the v2 folder, like so `<a href=`"v2/contact.html`"`>

Any help is MOST appreciated. I've spent hours trying to figure this out, but I'm only just learning about htaccess and regular expressions, and am totally confused.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^v2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hello, I try a very similar thing. I want www.example.com redirect to subfolder www.example.com/ss3, but ss3 should not be visible in the URL for the User. With your example that masking does not work. many thanx, florian

Answer (score 1):

rewrite everything by including v2 before it .

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v2/$1 [L] 

www.example.com/Page.html should now be processed as /v2/Page.html
```

You should not include v2/ in the url being sent to the user.

it would then become v2/v2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can see how that would work. I'm sorry that I haven't been clearer in my question - what I actually need to do is redirect anything that is not a child of the v2/ folder, TO the v2/ folder (www.example.com/v2) Regardless of the page on the old site (contact, products, about, etc.), I want them all to just redirect to the root of the v2/ folder. Because of all the subfolders on the old site, I need to figure out the regex for: SELECT everything IF v2 is NOT in the url, then Redirect (to use very un-techy speak) :) Thanks for answering!