# How to use redirections and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having problems using mod_rewrite and .htaccess.

I have a server and a domain: www.domain.com, inside de html_public I have a folder: my_folder, so I can acces the web contained in that forlder with this url: wwww.domain.com/my_folder.

I want to acces to that location using the url www.domain.com, but using only a redirection the url displayed is wwww.domain.com/my_folder. So I want to know how can I do to show www.domain.com instead.

Thanks

Joan

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect from root to subfolder and then mask the url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558237/htaccess-redirect-from-root-to-subfolder-and-then-mask-the-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file ( one directory level above `my_folder`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^my_folder /my_folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful. That's just what I wanted.